# Server process doesn't receive client's messages through sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets

I'm building a client-server project where the clients (it's actually a group of threads) makes some calculations and send the result to the server in an other process.

I want to open just 1 connection on the client side and send multiple "messages" through the socket. The first one goes just fine but then it stops sending.
I noticed that on the client side it keeps sending without errors but the server is stuck on 'accept' because it feels like it doesn't receive anything

What am i doing wrong?

server code:

```
int listenToSocket(int p) {
    int socket_fd, client_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t client_len;
    SocketInterface data;

    // Create socket
    socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_fd == -1) {
        perror("Error creating socket");
        return -1;
    }

    // Prepare server address structure
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Bind the socket to the specified port
    if (bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Error binding socket");
        close(socket_fd);
        return -1;
    }

    // Start listening on the socket
    if (listen(socket_fd, 1) < 0) {
        perror("Error listening on socket");
        close(socket_fd);
        return -1;
    }

    // Accept client connections and receive data continuously
    for(;; ) {
        client_len = sizeof(client_addr);

        client_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_len);
        if (client_fd < 0) {
            perror("Error accepting client connection");
            continue;
        }


        // Receive data into the struct
        if (read(client_fd, &data, sizeof(data)) < 0) {
            perror("Error receiving data");
            close(client_fd);
            continue;
        }

        if(data.over){
                break;
        }

        // Process the received struct data
        printf("%d      %3.2f        %3.2f            %50s\n", data.fd.n, data.fd.avg, data.fd.std, data.fd.path);

        //close(client_fd);
        memset(&client_addr, 0, sizeof (client_addr));
    }

    // Close the socket
    close(socket_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

construction of the socket in the main.c

```
    // create socket connection
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    // Create socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        perror("Error opening socket");
    }

    // Configure server address
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // Connect to server
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        close(sockfd);
        perror("Error connecting to server");
        kill(pid, SIGTERM);
        return -1;
    }
```

function called by the thread to send data (the sockfd is passed as an argument to the threads)

```
int sendThroughSocket(FileData *fd, int sockfd) {


    SocketInterface isock;
    if(fd != NULL){
        strcpy(isock.fd.path, fd->path);
        isock.fd.avg = fd->avg;
        isock.fd.std = fd->std;
        isock.fd.n = fd->n;
        isock.over = 0;
    }

    if (fd == NULL) {
        isock.over = 1;
    }

    if(fd != NULL){
        printf("Filename: %s, avg: %f std: %f\n",fd->path, fd->avg, fd->std);
    }else{
        printf("NUll is being sent\n");
    }
    if (write(sockfd, &isock, sizeof(isock)) < 0) {
        printf("Over: %d\n", isock.over);
        perror("Error sending data");
        return -1;
    }

    if(isock.over == 1){
        close(sockfd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even if the duplicate question is about Python the problems are the same: a) you do multiple accept even though there is only one client connect b) you assume that TCP has a concept of messages - which it has not.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives for both the client and the server program, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: I found out the problem. I need to use a select() implementation in the server